# UICollectionView Insertion animation curve

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Is it possible to adjust the animation curve for inserting indexPaths into a collectionview?

I am currently animating the insertion of items using this methods:

```
-initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:
```

However, I'd like the change the animation curve with which the layout animates items. Is this possible?

Comment: I propose wrapping `collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPath)` with `CATransaction` and setting appropriate timing function to this transaction.