# How do you slow down UICollectionView insert / delete animations?

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview

I know that you can have some degree of control over the insert and delete animations of `UICollectionView`s by overriding the `UICollectionViewLayout`methods

`initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:` for insertions
`finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:` for deletions

... but is there a way to change the animation's duration (e.g. to something much slower — 2 seconds or so?) or its animation curve?

Comment: I've seen answers like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690831/uicollectionview-animations-insert-delete-items already.

Comment: Another question asking the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662779/uicollectionview-insertion-animation-curve